# How to create a single element tensor in Pytorch with more than 0 dimensions?

Tags: pytorch

When I do

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor(1)
print(x.dim())
```

it gives `0`. I would like to create an `n-dimensional` scalar tensor. The only way I can do this is

```
torch.tensor(1).reshape([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

but I'm wondering if there's an way to do it from just the `torch.tensor` construction?

Comment: `torch.tensor([1])` or `torch.tensor([[1]])` and so on?